# QML on RaspberryPi - getting white screen

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qml

I have a small application in QML which works fine on my Linux machine. But when I try running it on Raspberry Pi, it shows a window with only white space inside. There's also a part of Text item - something like the last 3 characters - in the top left corner.

Various topics I found talked about missing QML files, but mine are in the same directory as the executable. When I try to move them, I get at least an error that they cannot be found.

Another thing is that when I run the app, CPU usage rises to as much as 300%.

On my laptop I have Qt 5.6.1, on RPi 5.3.2. I'm compiling the app on RPi, with libraries from Raspbian repository.

Not sure if related, but there's also a warning:
`libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate`

I also tried `export QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` to see what QML files are loading, and everything looks correct.

Loading the QML file in main.cpp looks like this:

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load("qml/MainWindow.qml");
```

I tried also using qrc, with the same result. And using QQuickView instead of QQmlApplicationEngine led to the same thing.

What could be the issue? Or where can I search for more info?

Edit:

I tried a QML example (texteditor), building using the same tools as my app. The example works without any issues, so the problem must be in my code.

Comment: I had errors like yours when my application missed QML system folders ie QtQml, QtQuick, QtQuick.2.

Comment: @folibis not likely the issue, with QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1 I'm getting messages like:
QQmlImports(file:///home/pi/wamenu/qml/MainWindow.qml)::importExtension: loaded "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir", which looks like it loads the correct QML files from the system path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might encounter the same issue.

The problem was in setting dimensions based on Window, like this:

```qml
Rectagle {
    width: Window.width
}
```

Changed to:

```
Rectagle {
    width: mainWindow.width
}
```

Where `mainWindow` is id of the Window item in the main QML file.

Not sure why this worked on Linux PC and not on Raspbian.